# landscape.canonical.com slow/not respoding since yesterday

Tags: landscape

I got issue with landscape.canonical.com since yesterday. Landscape randomly notify me that few of my computer did not contact landscape for last 5 minutes. I try to register a new compute without success (timeout). I also trying to reach https://landscape.canonical.com/message-system but if fails 1/2 times.

Any ongoing issue with landscape.canonical.com?

Thank You

Comment: It's timing out for me too.  Must be down.

Answer (score -1):

No alert since 12AM, seems to be ok now